# Problems with a 'myrange' loop continuing to process beyond the end of the range

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find

I am having problems with a macro which should search for each `mycell` of `myrange` in turn and copy it to another sheet if it is found in the GL sheet. However it continues to run after the cells in `myrange` (i.e. it continues to run on all the blank rows under `myrange`). `myrange` is just 10 rows of data.  Here is the code:

```
Dim myrange As Range
Dim mycell As Range

   Set wbProjects = Workbooks("Expense Project Jobs.xlsx")
   Set wbGL = Workbooks("GL.xml")
   Set wbProjectJournal = Workbooks("Expense Project Journal.xlsx")

wbProjects.Activate
LastrowJob1 = Sheets("Project_Costs").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myrange = Range("F2:F" & LastrowJob1)

'LOOP START

For Each mycell In myrange
If mycell = "" Then
GoTo ErrorHandlerMyCell
End If

mycell.Copy
wbGL.Activate

On Error GoTo ErrorHandlerMyCell

Range("A1").Activate
Cells.Find(What:=mycell, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

   On Error GoTo 0

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut
    wbProjectJournal.Activate
    Range("A1").Activate
    If Range("A2") <> "" Then
    GoTo NextCode2

NextCode2:
     Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Activesheet.Paste
    wbGL.Activate
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

    Else
    Range("A2").Select
    Activesheet.Paste

    End If

NextCode1:
    Next mycell

ErrorHandlerMyCell:
    Resume NextCode1

End Sub
```

Comment: I may be going blind (your indentation does not help either) but I can't seem to find a `Next` for the end of your loop

Comment: why all the error checking, selecting and activating?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that your code will run ErrorHandlerMyCell at the end irregardless of whether there's an error or not? It's not a separate module that is called only when there's error but part of the main program which gets triggered. Perhaps you can add a Exit Sub before ErrorHandlerMyCell

```
Exit Sub
ErrorHandlerMyCell:
Resume NextCode1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code have plenty of redundancies and it seems to be overwriting records copied in `Row 3` when cell `A2` in `wbProjectJournal` is empty.

I also suggest to set the worksheets as `objects` instead of the workbooks. Actually the code ends up working with whatever is the active sheet in the workbooks after they are activated. It could be working now if there is only one sheet or if the one active is the one required, but it’s just a coincidence, not a good practice.

One point to highlight is the excessive and incorrect use of what is intended to act as `Error Handlers` *(see this page [On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx) for a better understanding)*, also to improve use of objects see this *[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264723(v=office.15).aspx)*

The code below should solve the issue, *(have inserted comments to explain the changes)*:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST_Solution()
Dim wbProjects As Workbook, wbGL As Workbook, wbProjectJournal As Workbook
Dim rTrg As Range, rCll As Range, rCllTrg As Range
Dim rFnd As Range, vWhat As Variant

    Set wbProjects = Workbooks("Expense Project Jobs.xlsx")
    Set wbGL = Workbooks("GL.xml")
    Set wbProjectJournal = Workbooks("Expense Project Journal.xlsx")
    wbProjects.Activate

    Rem Set Range from wbProjects\Project_Costs\Column F
    'use [With] to perform several statements on the same object
    'see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264723(v=office.15).aspx
    With wbProjects.Sheets("Project_Costs").Columns(6)
        Set rTrg = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Rem Search for the value of each cell in the no-empty cells of
    For Each rCll In rTrg

        Rem Set & Validate cell value
        vWhat = rCll.Value2
        If vWhat <> Empty Then

            Rem Activate range to apply the FIND method
            'Replace [1] with the name of the worksheet where the search is run
            With wbGL.Sheets(1)
                .Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1

                Rem Set cell with found value
                Set rFnd = .Cells.Find(What:=vWhat, After:=ActiveCell, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not (rFnd Is Nothing) Then

                    Rem Activate range to apply the FIND method
                    'Replace [1] with the name of the worksheet where the search is performed
                    With wbProjectJournal.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
                        If .Value2 = Empty Then
                            Rem A2 = Blank then Paste in row 2 only
                            rFnd.EntireRow.Copy
                            .PasteSpecial
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False

                        ElseIf .Offset(1).Value2 = Empty Then
                            Rem A3 = Blank then Paste in row 3 & delete record found
                            rFnd.EntireRow.Copy
                            .Offset(1).PasteSpecial
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            rFnd.EntireRow.Delete

                        Else
                            Rem Paste below last row & delete record found
                            rFnd.EntireRow.Copy
                            .End(xlDown).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            rFnd.EntireRow.Delete

        End If: End With: End If: End With: End If: Next

End Sub
```